# SSRS multiple column values into 1 parameter

Tags: .net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to develop an SSRS report that contains 1 parameter that is linked to multiple column values. Suppose I am creating a report for a company that has various departments and these departments fall under 2 organizations within the company:

```
EmployeeID |Name  | Dept_number
-------------------------------
1          |Tom   | AB12
2          |Bob   | AB10
3          |John  | AB08
4          |Kim   | AB09
5          |Jack  | AB05
```

I am able to create a parameter for each department number, but what I want to do is aggregate the department numbers into one parameter with 2 options: Organization A & Organization B. Is there a way to do this in SSRS when I am connecting directly to the database?

Comment: Is the link between Organisation and Department stored in the data anywhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supposing these table structures:

```
CREATE TABLE Depts (DepartmentId INT, Dept_number VARCHAR(4), OrganizationId INT)
CREATE TABLE Orgs (OrganizationId INT, Org_name VARCHAR(50))
```

You can fill parameter values like this:

```
SELECT Dept_number, Org_name + ': ' + Dept_number AS OptionText
FROM   Depts
       JOIN Orgs ON Orgs.OrganizationId = Depts.OrganizationId
```

And then query your SSRS dataset with a where clause:

```
SELECT *
FROM   Employee
WHERE  Employee.Dept_number = @MySsrsParameter
```